# What is the right syntax to pass environment variables to application.properties in Spring Boot at docker container creation?

Tags: docker, spring-boot, environment-variables

I would like to pass environment variables from my docker container to my Spring Boot application.properties, when I run the container. I have the following application.properties file.

```
#application.properties
spring.datasource.url=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}
spring.datasource.username=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

My docker commands for creating the container looks the following:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -e SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL:'<my url>' -e SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME:'<my username>' -e SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD:'<my password>' -e --name mycontainer  mycontainer
```

The container crushes with: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'`

What would be the right syntax?

Comment: Did you try something like `jdbc:mysql://db_server:3306/some_database` ?

Comment: yes, with postgres

Comment: You should elaborate more... exactly what string did you pass as datasource url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a syntax error in the `docker run` command:

`-e SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL:'<my url>'`

You must use the `=` sign for environmental variable assignment, not `:`

`-e SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL='<my url>'`

Comment: yes, thanks that was the problem, though now I am facing another problem. ${SPRING_RABBITMQ_PORT}
    Reason: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int' for property 'port'; with my rabbitmq properties.

Comment: Try to pass the port without enclosing it in single marks, for example: `SPRING_RABBITMQ_PORT=1234`

Comment: I have tried that. Doesn't work. I will create a new question, so you might get the rewards for the answer.

Comment: gabor, can you put the link to the new question here?

Comment: what if it is a application.yml file then how to do with that?